# How do I grow the existing swap volume on a debian aws machine?

Tags: debian, swap

Running a debian server on aws. `lsblk` reports:

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
<snip>
nvme1n1      259:1    0    2G  0 disk [SWAP]
<snip>
```

However, `free` reports swap is only 1GB:

```
Mem:         3979208      651520     2879284       62296      448404     3047640
Swap:        1048572           0     1048572
```

I can't figure out how to get the server to use the full 2GB swap volume. I tried rebooting, tried resize2fs, tried growpart, swapon/off, fallocate, etc. None of it has worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get UUID of device: `sudo blkid`
2. Turn swap off: `sudo swapoff -a`
3. Create swap: `sudo mkswap -U <UUID_FROM_STEP_1> /dev/nvmeXnX` (where x is a number).
4. Turn swap on: `sudo swapon /dev/nvme1n1`